# How to use absolute url in trix image path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, trix

I have used gem 'trix' to integrate trix-editor feature in rails app.

However while testing on staging environment, the trix_editor content field shows the relative path of image.

```
<img src="/images/2036780.jpg" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;">
```

Is there a way I can use image_url or something to define absolute path of image for images inside trix_editor content field as in

```
<img src="https://asdf.cloudfront.net/images/2036780.jpg" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;">
```

Comment: For those still struggling with this, I replaced src from images on content with image_url. That way it was able to fetch image from absolute path and worked perfectly.